# Kafka consumer API is not working properly

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka .i started doing  on Kafka i am facing below issue please help me to solve this one thank in advance.
First i am writing producer API it is working fine but while doing  Consumer API messages are not display.

My code is like this :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;


public class ConsumerGroup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String topic = "Hello-Kafka";
        String group = "myGroup";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "XXX.XX.XX.XX:9092");
        props.put("group.id", group);
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
        try {

            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
            System.out.println("Subscribed to topic " + topic);


            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);

            System.out.println("records ::" + records);
            System.out.println(records.toString());
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.println("Record::" + record.offset());
                System.out.println(record.key());
                System.out.println(record.value());
            }
            consumer.commitSync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.commitSync();
            consumer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Response ::

Subscribed to topic Hello-Kafka
records ::org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords@76b0bfab
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords@76b0bfab

here not printing the Offset,key,value 
Control is not coming to for (ConsumerRecord record : records) {
that for loop it self please help me.

Comment: Have you produced some messages to the topic?
 Seems like your topic has no messages

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print empty records, hence only records.toString() is printing in your code, which essentially is the name of the class.
 I made some changes in your code and got it working. Do have a look if this helps.

```
public class ConsumerGroup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String topic = "Hello-Kafka";
        String group = "myGroup";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "xx.xx.xx.xx:9092");
        props.put("group.id", group);
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
        try {

            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
            System.out.println("Subscribed to topic " + topic);

            while(true){
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
                if(records.isEmpty()){

                }
                else{
                System.out.println("records ::" + records);
                System.out.println(records.toString());
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    System.out.println("Record::" + record.offset());
                    System.out.println(record.key());
                    System.out.println(record.value());
                }
                consumer.commitSync();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.commitSync();
            consumer.close();
        }
    }
}
```